# Kendo dropdownList popup out with auto width

Tags: kendo-ui

I have kendo dropdownlist which is having large value and its not fitted  automatically with its result. please help.

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
<select id="serviceAccounts"
    kendo-drop-down-list
    k-ng-model="vm.customer.serviceAccountId"
    k-value-primitive="true"
    k-options="vm.setServiceAccountOptions" style="width: 100%">
```

function

```
function setServiceAccountOptions() {
vm.setServiceAccountOptions = {
    dataSource: { data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listServiceAccount")) },
    dataTextField: 'dataTextField',
    dataValueField: 'serviceAccountId',
    change: function () {
    acctSearchService.getServiceAccountsById(this.value())
    .then(getServiceAccountSuccess, getServiceAccountFailure);
    },
    template:
    "<table><tr><td>${ serviceAccountId } : </td><td>${ serviceAccountStatus } </td><td>${ serviceType } - </td><td>${ serviceAddress}</td></tr></table>"
    }; }
```

[This how its looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUz7o.jpg)

[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ZqD.jpg)

is it possible with kendo dropdownlist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example about this in the documentation website:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/how-to/auto-adjust-the-width

Comment: Hey Dimodi, you rocks... Thanks, you have resolved my problem. Cheers.